# Case class's apply method type

Tags: scala, types, case-class

I was trying to use `type` field, but it seems I did something wrong. It seems to be working with classic classes, but for some reason type of case class's `apply` doesn't match.

```
object Common {
    type EntityId = Long
}
import Common._

abstract class IdStore {
  self =>
  type Entity
  type Ref <: IdRef[_]
  type Self <: IdStore {type Entity = self.Entity; type Ref = self.Ref}

  def apply(data: Map[Ref, Entity]): Self

  def data: Map[Ref, Entity]

  def merge(other: Self): Self = apply(data ++ other.data)
}

trait IdRef[T] {
  def id: T
}

trait EntityIdRef extends IdRef[EntityId] {}


class TestStore(val data: Map[IdRef[Int], Object]) extends IdStore {
  override type Entity = Object
  override type Ref = IdRef[Int]
  override type Self = TestStore

  override def apply(data: Map[Ref, Entity]): Self = new TestStore(data)
}

case class TestCaseClassStore(data: Map[IdRef[Int], Object]) extends IdStore {
  override type Entity = Object
  override type Ref = IdRef[Int]
  override type Self = TestCaseClassStore
}
```

#### Error

```
Main.scala:34: error: class TestCaseClassStore needs to be abstract, since method apply in class IdStore of type (data: Map[TestCaseClassStore.this.Ref,TestCaseClassStore.this.Entity])TestCaseClassStore.this.Self is not defined
case class TestCaseClassStore(data: Map[IdRef[Int], Object]) extends IdStore {
           ^
one error found
```

Code is also available at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/m1TCAy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you got one detail about case classes wrong:

Case classes do not come with free apply functions!

They come with a companion object that has a factory `apply` function to create new instances of your case class. That is:

```
case class Foo(bar: Int)
```

is similar to

```
class Foo(val bar: Int)
object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Int): Foo = new Foo(bar)
}
```

So, in your code

```
case class TestCaseClassStore(data: Map[IdRef[Int], Object]) extends IdStore {
  override type Entity = Object
  override type Ref = IdRef[Int]
  override type Self = TestCaseClassStore
}
```

is missing the `apply` function required in `IdStore`.

Considering this, are you sure that the `apply` function defined in `IdStore` is what you want?

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid now, it should have been `copy`, not `apply`... Thanks for pointing that out clearly.

Answer (score 2):

What the error message says and I think it's what's happening, is that you did an override of all types of IdStore, but didn't do so for the "apply" method.

You've got it right for the "TestStore" class, but not in "TestCaseClassStore".

Comment: Everyone here got it right, I mixed up `copy` and `apply`. Thanks for answering :).

Comment: No worries, glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 2):

That's simply because a `case class` does *not* have an `apply()` method. It's *companion object* gets an `apply` method, but not the *class*.

To give you a *solution* to your problem, though, we would need to know more about what is the expected *usage* of `IdStore` and its subclasses. Assuming `IdStore` is perfect, you probably don't want `TestCaseClassStore` to be a `case class` in the first place.

Comment: Everyone here got it right, I mixed up `copy` and `apply`. Thanks for answering :).